# C++ / SDL encapsulation design help

Tags: c++, oop, sdl

So I am semi-new to C++, and completely new to SDL. Most of my conceptual knowledge of OOP comes from Java and PHP. So bear with me.

I am trying to work out some simple design logic with my program / soon to be side-scroller. My problem lies with trying to make my 'screen' layer (`screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(...)`) accessible to all my other classes; Hero class, background layer, enemies, etc. I have been loosely following some more procedural tutorials, and have been trying to adapt them to a more object oriented approach. Here is a little bit of what I have so far:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Hero.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Init Game
    Game Game;

    //Load hero
    Hero Hero(Game.screen);

    //While game is running
    while(Game.runningState())
    {
        //Handle Window and Hero inputs
        Game.Input();
        Hero.userInput();

        //Draw
        Game.DrawBackground();
        Hero.drawHero();

        //Update
        Game.Update();
    }

    //Clean up
    Game.Clean();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have a Game class, and a Hero class. The Game class is responsible for setting up the initial window, and placing a background. It also updates the screen as you can see.

Now, since my Game class holds the 'screen' property, which is a handle for `SDL_SetVideoMode`, I am stuck passing this into any other class (`ex: Hero Hero(Game.screen);`) that needs to update to this screen... say via `SDL_BlitSurface`.

Now, this works, however I am getting the idea there has GOT to be a more elegant approach. Like possibly keeping that `screen` handler on the global scope (if possible)?

***TLDR / Simple version***: What is the best way to go about making my window / screen handler accessible to all my subsequent classes?

Comment: Try to avoid having variables with the same names as classes, such as `Hero Hero` and `Game Game`. It makes things more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `Game.screen` around is more OO (though it might be better to have a getter function) than having one instance of it that can be accessed from any class, because if you have one global version, you can't have more than one `Game.screen` at any one time.

However if you know you'll only ever need one in the entire lifetime of the program, you might consider making `Game::Screen()` a public static function in the `Game` class that returns a private static member `screen`. That way, anyone can call `Game::Screen()` and get the `screen`.

Example (assuming `ScreenType` is the type of `screen` and that you store a pointer to it):

```
class Game {
public:
    static ScreenType* Screen() {
        if (!screen)
            screen = GetScreenType(args);
        return screen; 
    }
}

private:
    // if you don't already know:
    // static means only one of this variable exists, *not* one per instance
    // so there is only one no matter how many instances you make
    // the same applies to static functions, which you don't need an instance to call
    static ScreenType* screen;
};

// and somewhere in a .cpp file
ScreenType* Game::screen = NULL;

// and you use it like this
ScreenType* scr = Game::Screen();
// use scr
```

Comment: There will only be one screen for my purposes. Could you possilby show an example of setting up a static (method?) in this way. Does this just return the screen handler / variable?

Comment: OK. That's horribly bad. If you are going to give advice about using singeltons at least do it properly. The classical example of "Myers Singelton" is a reasonable way of doing it you are going to do it. On the whole though a singelton is not the way to go.

Comment: @Tux-D I'm not giving advice about singletons. I'm just doing what works. Also, to counteract this horrible answer, please make an answer and show the OP the correct way to do a singleton (which wasn't my aim).

Comment: @Tux-D No room for this. He showed me an example of something which solves my problem. I am asking for best ways to go about this, and if you find a better / more elegant solution, please post it. Do not discredit other answers however.

Comment: @Tux-D also this is not a singleton class, which is why I didn't add a private ctor and the other accouterments of proper singletons. Only the `GetScreen()` function belongs to the whole class instead of individual members. That's what I assume, and Headspin didn't indicate differently.

Comment: @Headspin: Easy. A better way is not to do this. But that is what I said above.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: It's not only horrible because of that. You are returning a pointer. You are asking the user of the object t initiate cleanup of the object. Basically it hits all the bad points of object design in C++. This also makes testing (using dependency injection) next to imposable.

Comment: @Tux-D returning a pointer is not a bad design. Also only one game object will be created for the entire application and its entire lifetime, so the user doesn't need to clean it up.

Comment: @Seth: Returning a pointer in C++ is bad design. It has no concept of ownership. Without the concept of ownership we have no clue who is responsible for cleanup. This is ultimately going to lead to bugs down the road. Good C++ code practically never has any pointer it it (smart pointers or references). In this case a reference would (probably) have been the correct solution. Please look up a "Meyers Singelton"

Comment: @Tux-D bad design is highly subjective, so I won't even go into that. A reference would be more prone to misuse because someone might accidentally create a copy instead of a reference to the return value. And again, this isn't a singleton class.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Bad design is not subjective! You are now pointing more reasons why it is bad design. Good design would not allow the object to be accidentally misused. C++ has the philosophy that it is the creator of the class that is responsible for making sure that the object can not be misused (why do you think streams are non copyable).

Comment: @Tux-D I said a _reference_ would be prone to error. And yes, bad design is subjective, which is why we're conversing about it.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Reference are not prone to error as they are just aliases. The underlying object is just badly designed. End of story. As I mentioned before please do some research. Myers has whole sections about this in his books.

Comment: @Tux-D references are more prone to error in this instance because someone can do `ScreenType a = Game::Screen()` instead of `ScreenType& a = Game::Screen()` or whatever, which will not produce a compiler error but make a copy of the screen. Also please do not result to personal insults in conversations.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: It is more prone to errors here because the class is badly designed. It has nothing to do with references and more to do with the way the code is written. You started out along a singelton path but decided because it was an anti-pattern that you would not go all the way. But this just made your code even more brittle as now there are opportunities to make accidental copies of the object. So you basically have the worst of two worlds. A singleton like point of tight coupling and a fragile object that will break when you accidentally copy it.

Answer (score 2):

I like the way you are doing it.

Though rather than passing the screen reference I would pass a reference to a game itself. Thus each hero object knows which game it belongs too, it can then ask the game object for the screen as required.

The reason I would do this is so that in a few years when your game is a wide and successful product and you convert it for online-play you really need to do no work. The game server will be able to easily support multiple game objects, each game object hosting multiple hero objects. As each hero object wants to draw it asks the game for the screen abd updates the screen (the screen can now very from game object to game object and still work perfectly (as long as they have the same interface).

```
class Game
{
   public:
       Game(Screen& screen)
          : screen(screen)
       {}
       virtual ~Game()           {}
       virtual Screen&  screen() { return theGameScreen;}

       void update() { /* Draw Screen. Then draw all the heros */ }

   private:
       friend Hero::Hero(Game&);
       friend Hero::~Hero();
       void addHero(Hero& newHero) {herosInGame.push_back(&newHero);}
       void delHero(Hero& newHeor) {/* Delete Hero from herosInGame */}

       // Implementation detail about how a game stores a screen
       // I do not have enough context only that a Game should have one
       // So theoretically:

       Screen&              theGameScreen;
       std::vector<Hero*>   herosInGame;


};

class Hero
{
    public:
        Hero(Game& game)
            : game(game)
         {game.addHero(*this);}
        virtual ~Hero()
         {game.delHero(*this);}


         virtual void Draw(Screen& screen)  {/* Draw a hero on the screen */}
     private:
         Game& game;
};
```

Main.

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Hero.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Init Game
    Screen   aScreenObject
    Game     game(aScreenObject);

    //Load hero
    Hero     hero(game);             // or create one hero object for each player


    //While game is running
    while(game.runningState())
    {
        //Handle Window and Hero inputs
        Game.Input();
        Hero.userInput();

        //Update
        Game.update();
    }

    //Clean up
    // Game.Clean(); Don't do this
    //               This is what the destructor is for.
}
```

Comment: +1 but I'd add that the server side version of `Game` wouldn't have a `Screen` because no drawing is done server side. But that's not relevant to the principle.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Yes it is. And that is the whole point of this design. On the server end what it will be doing is sending update events to the client. But neither the game nor the player object need to know this. To them it is just a screen how it works is irrelevant to them.

Comment: To be honest, I do not doubt this is a good approach, however being new to C++, I am not very sure what is going on here, ha!

Comment: @Headspin: The basic premises is don't use singeltons (or a single point global point to get state from). Do this makes the code brittle and hard to test. If you read up on Sigeltons you will find they are considered anti-patterns.

Comment: I am very familiar with Singletons. However I do feel they have their place. If this is not one of those cases, could you please explain a little more in detail as to what is going on here, and how I can implement this? I would very much appreciate it, and if you can convince me this is the best way, then I will have to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's elegant, but what I do for the side-scrolling game I'm making is to make a `show()` function in each class than draws to the screen, and passing the screen handle as a parameter. Then whenever I want to draw something to the screen I just do `foo.show(screen)`. The screen handle is in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

The first, and honestly, easiest solution, is to use a global variable.  Yes, yes, yes, everyone says global variables are horrible, but in this situation, it's perfectly fine.

The other solution, which is a bit more work, but can result in somewhat more portable code, is to encapsulate your drawing functions into a single, static class.  This way, you can draw to the screen directly without having to pass around a variable, or have to lie awake at night thinking the code review police will get you because you used a global variable.  Plus, this can potentially make it easier if you ever decide to port your game to a new library.  Some quick and dirty pseudocode:

```
class Drawing
  public:
    static void Draw(x, y, sdl_surface graphic, sdl_rect & clip=null);
    static void init(sdl_surface & screen);
  private:
    sdl_surface screen;

void Drawing::Draw(x, y, sdl_surface graphic, sdl_rect & clip=null)
{
  sdl_blit(x, y, graphic, clip);
}

void Drawing::init(sdl_surface & screen)
{
  this.screen=screen;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to implement the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern, where you would have a single `Screen` object. If you know you're only ever going to have a single `Screen` object it should work fine.

In this case you would implement a static method on the `Game` class:

```
class Game
{
    public:
        static Game *GetTheSceenObject();
    private:
        static Screen *theScreen;    // details of initialisation ommitted
}
```

that would return a pointer to the single `Screen` object.

---

If there is a possibility that you'll end up using multiple SDL screens, though, it may be worth creating a `Draw()` method in your `Hero` class that is responsible for drawing the hero on each of the `Screen`s managed by the `Game` class by iterating through a list provided by the `Game` class.

That functionality could be contained in the methods of a common `DrawableThingy` class that `Hero` and `Enemy` are derived from.